# "E21: cannot make changes" when editing resolv.conf

Tags: vim, resolv.conf

A few hours earlier I bought a beaglebone and now I am trying to add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `/etc/resolv.conf`. However when I open it with vim and try to add my nameserver, it gives me E21: cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off. I changed permissions via chmod. `chmod u+rx /etc/resolv.conf` But nothing changed. I am still unable to write into resolv.conf file. What should I do?

Comment: Also just to confirm are you using 12.04 because it doesn't support resolv.conf any more. The changes just get overwritten.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to add something and now edited my question: I am trying to edit resolv.conf existing on my beaglebone which is operating angstrom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From vim documentation:

If you make changes to a file and forgot that it was read-only, you can
still write it.  Add the ! to the write command to force writing.

If you really want to forbid making changes in a file, do this:

```
vim -M file
```

Now every attempt to change the text will fail.  The help files are like this,
for example.  If you try to make a change you get this error message:

```
E21: Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off
```

You could use the -M argument to setup Vim to work in a viewer mode.  This is
only voluntary though, since these commands will remove the protection:

```
:set modifiable
:set write
```

Comment: This will only work if `vim` is actually capable of writing the file. If `vim` opens a file as a regular user that can only be changed as root, then `vim` will not be able to save the changes to the file.

Comment: Try with `chmod 777 /etc/resolv.conf` but don't forget to set it back!

Comment: It's preferable to run `vim` as `root` (`sudo vim ...`)--that way, the file is never changeable by any unauthorized user or process, and you don't have to change permissions.

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/resolv.conf` is owned by `root`, so you must edit it as `root` ([using `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)):

```
sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
```

You might want to back it up first though:

```
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.old
```

If you prefer to edit it graphically, then instead of using `vim`, you can use:

```
gksu gedit /etc/resolv.conf
```

Or on Kubuntu:

```
kdesudo kate /etc/resolv.conf
```

If you changed `/etc/resolv.conf`'s permissions, you should change them back, as the default permissions prevent unauthorized access while allowing authorized access as explained above.

However, it's likely you didn't really change any permissions, since by default (at least on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) `/etc/resolv.conf` is actually a symbolic link to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I caused a misunderstanding because of the reason that I forgot to add that I am trying to edit resolv.conf file on my beaglebone which is operating angstrom.
Again, sorry for the inconvenience. If you still have an idea and share with me, I will be appreciate to you.

Comment: @Zxy You can run `vim /etc/resolv.conf`. So you should be able to run `sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf`. That is, if you're using Ubuntu. If you're using another distro, like the [Ångström distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m_distribution), then your questions is off-topic for AskUbuntu and you should ask it at [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/resolv.conf
```

That will let you modify the file and save it.

You can try:

```
opkg update
opkg install gedit
```

Comment: currently I am not able to connect to net because of my dns options. therefore I cannot use opkg install gedit. however thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

*(Disclaimer: this is based on Internet research, not on actual hands-on experience with the board.)*

According to [this](http://www.gigamegablog.com/2012/01/29/beaglebone-linux-101-configuring-angstrom-linux/) article,

> [Ångström Linux](http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/) distribution [...] is included in the microSD card
>   packaged with each Beaglebone.

Without citing the whole article (it seems to be very well written, btw.) you need to:

1. SSH into your Beagleboard as root.
2. Edit `/etc/network/interfaces`.
3. Add `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8`.
4. Run `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

If your settings seem to work, but go away after a reboot, read [this](http://www.gigamegablog.com/2012/02/06/beaglebone-linux-101-assigning-a-static-ip-address-with-connman/) article on setting up Connman.

You'll need to install the `connman-tests` package to enable command-line configuration of Connman, and set the nameservers by following the instructions.

Example:

```
./set-nameservers ethernet_405fc276b749_cable 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
vim resolv.conf
```

Save it after that

```
rm -rf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then move resolv.conf file in /etc/

```
mv resolv.conf /etc/
```